# How jspm determines what to download from Github

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jspm

I've been struggling trying to download the less files from Twitter Bootstrap. According to jspm documentation they will download the release's zip file instead of the source code in the repository. In Twitter Bootstrap that zip file doesn't have the less files, so I understand why I don't get them when I do something like:

```
jspm install github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.4
```

However, in order to avoid that limitation, I forked Twitter Bootstrap to avoid those custom release files. When I go to the releases section in my fork and download the file, it looks good, but when I try to install it I got the the same files as before.

I did a clean cache, created a different branch, made changes on a new branch based on v3.3.4, etc., etc. I always get the same set of files of v3.3.4 without the less files.

Does anyone knows how jspm determines what to download and why it might be downloading the release file in twbs/bootstrap instead of the one in my fork?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a little late but stumbled upon this while searching on another topic. So basically here's the deal.

jspm leverages the package.json file. You'll notice an entry called "files". When jspm hits the github/npm repo it will look at this JSON key and determine what to pull.

This is useful because often you may have a module that requires other files to dev but you don't want or need those files when distributing the module.

As you can see below this is the "files" config in the bootstrap package.json. It does have a key for the less files.

```
"files": [
  "dist",
  "fonts",
  "grunt",
  "js/*.js",
  "less/**/*.less",
  "Gruntfile.js",
  "LICENSE"
],
```

The issue here, if you want to call it that is in how jspm is handling this popular repo. Internally it maps for some repos it maps to distros and in this case bootstrap-less. You can see all the bootstrap jspm registry entries below:

```
"bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap",
"bootstrap-less": "github:distros/bootstrap-less",
"bootstrap-material": "github:fezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design",
"bootstrap-sass": "github:twbs/bootstrap-sass",
"bootstrap-slider": "github:seiyria/bootstrap-slider",
"bootstrap-wizard": "github:gwrey/bootstrap-wizard"
```

So if you want the less files you need merely run:

```
$ jspm install bootstrap-less
```

Anyone can create a pull request and add to the jspm registry. You can find the registry at this link:

https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/master/registry.json

Hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: The sass files for the bootstrap 4.0 alpha are not available in bootstrap-sass repo. I ended up using npm for now instead as i couldn't find a jspm solution `"git+https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#v4-dev"`